# memory management on Protocol

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am using protocol,and getting leak,
Here is my code :

```
+ (id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy>)strategyFromType:(GMGridViewLayoutStrategyType)type
{
    id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy> strategy = nil;

    switch (type) {
        case GMGridViewLayoutVertical:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutVerticalStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontal:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTR:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTRStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
        case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTB:
            strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTBStrategy alloc] init];
            break;
    }

    return strategy;
}
```

if I do autorelease then it will be crashed.so what should I do now?please help me...
Thank You...

Comment: When it crashes with autorelase? In this method or outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `strategyFromType` function

```
return [strategy autorelease];
```

When you call this function use `retain`

```
GMGridViewLayoutStrategy *strat = [[YourClassName strategyFromType:yourType] retain];
```

After use of strat variable

```
[strat release];
```

Comment: so can i write autorelease there?

Comment: 'there' means? you can either write autorelease with return statement like I have done.. Or you can use `[[[yourClass alloc ] init] autorelease]`

Comment: hi
I have custom tabbar.In tabbar, when i am going back i am calling one method using NSNotificationCenter.In that method i am just releasing all the objects.but when i checked
it in instrument i found that allocated objects are not going to dealloc.Code is here:`-(void)backBtnPessed
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GeneralViewController" object:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}`
please help me.Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy>)strategyFromType:(GMGridViewLayoutStrategyType)type
{id<GMGridViewLayoutStrategy> strategy = nil;

switch (type) {
    case GMGridViewLayoutVertical:
        strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutVerticalStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
    case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontal:
        strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
    case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTR:
        strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedLTRStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
    case GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTB:
        strategy = [[GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedTTBStrategy alloc] init];
        break;
}

return [strategy autorelease];
}
```

at the calling side..

```
GMGridViewLayoutStrategy *obj = [[YourClassName strategyFromType:yourType] retain];
```

after using "obj" release it.